# 32 bit iMac, will 64 bit run properly?

Tags: osx, installation

I am ready to download Blender. I have and older iMac, 20", 32 bit. It has memory upgrade to 4GB and the latest Yosemite. I only see the option for 64bit for download. Is there still a 32 bit or does it not matter?

Comment: If your system is 32bit, load blender's 32bit version. If it's the wrong one it won't run on your system. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is  about operating systems and not in scope.

Comment: I don't know specificity for a mac, but in general a 32bit program will run on a 64bit system. However it will *not* work the other way around, you can not run a 64bit program on a 32bit system.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Sorry the question is off topic. I'm new to this forum and navigating is a bit awkward for me. BTW, Downloaded latest version of Blender, it is working fine. Now if only I can learn how to use it.....;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender dropped support for the 32bit versions of OSX in 2.72.
To your question about running a 64bit version on your 32bit system, I will direct you [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/103996).
If you find that you can not use any 64bit software, because of your CPU or some other reason; then you can still use 2.71 with no problem.
[Download link](http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.71/blender-2.71-OSX_10.6-j2k-fix-i386.zip) for 2.71 32bit OSX on blender's server.

Comment: Thank so much David!! The secondary thread you directed me to answered the quest and instructed me on how to find if I am running 32 or 64. Turns out I am running 64 bit. This is one less thing for me to worry about, thanks again!